# ```PiecewiseExpand``` doesn't work as expected with a recursive function

Tags: recursion, piecewise

In an effort to examine [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634171/rate-of-convergence-of-a-bisection-like-algorithm) on Math.SE, I defined the following functions

```
c[n_, x_] := (a[n - 1, x] + b[n - 1, x])/4 + x/2;
a[n_, x_] := 
  Return[If[n == 0, 0, t = c[n, x]; If[t > x, a[n - 1, x], t]]];
b[n_, x_] := 
  Return[If[n == 0, 1, t = c[n, x]; If[t > x, t, b[n - 1, x]]]];
```

These functions work as expected and return the correct output. However, when I call `PiecewiseExpand[a[2, x]]` I get the output of

```
1/4 (1 + 2 x) if x >= 1/22
0 else
```

This is clearly wrong - `a[2, 0.3] = 0.25` while $\frac{1+2\cdot0.3}{4} = 0.4$. For some reason, `PiecewiseExpand` is not working properly here. Why is this happening, and how can I fix this problem?

Edit: At the suggestion of Nasser, I changed the functions to

```
c[n_, x_] := (a[n - 1, x] + b[n - 1, x])/4 + x/2;
a[n_, x_] := 
  If[n == 0, 0, t = c[n, x]; If[t > x, a[n - 1, x], t, "idk"], "idk1"];
b[n_, x_] := 
  If[n == 0, 1, t = c[n, x]; If[t > x, t, b[n - 1, x], "idk"], "idk1"];
```

Now with `PiecewiseExpand[a[1, x], {0 < x < 1}]`, the output is `idk`.

Comment: it is because  of this. `If[t > x, a[n - 1, x], t]`  you need to use the `If` with 3 arguments version. `If[t > x, a[n - 1, x], t, "do not know" ]`. 
Since it is not able to decide if `t>x` when `x` is symbolic. It works with `x` is a number, since then it is able to decide. And why do you need to use all these `Return` for? Just get rid of them.

Comment: After changing the if statement to that, ```PiecewiseExpand``` just returns the fourth argument (```"do not know"```).

Comment: That is correct. That is the expected result. How would you decide if `2>x` or not if `x` is symbolic?  Not possible. This is your algorithm. So you need to figure what to do in this case. It works when `x` is number. These issues do not show up in say Matlab, because Matlab is all numbers. So no need for the 3 branch `If`. But in Mathematica it is needed.

Comment: Does that mean that there is no way to expand ```a[2, x]``` into piecewise functions in Mathematica? If so, I might just have to do this in Matlab.

Comment: No, it does not mean that. I meant you need to decide, based on your algorithm, what to use in the 3rd branch for `If` when x is symbolic. I did not look at your algorithm itself. Sorry no time. But may be your algorithm itself is not implemented correctly. All what I am saying, you initially got the result you saw is because of this issue. Make sure you are implementing the algorithm you saw correctly is all what I can suggest now.

Comment: I had quick look at the link you showed. Notice it says `for x∈(0,1)` so `x` in that algorithm is a specific numerical value. Not symbolic.

Comment: Even with the assumption that $0 < x < 1$, ```PiecewiseExpand``` was not able to expand it (in my edit).

Comment: No, it is not an assumption., In the algorithm you are trying to implement, `x` has to be given and it must be a number between 0 and 1. can not be symbolic, Otherwise you can't do it. I said all what I can on this. May be someone else can provide better help. good luck.